# How to create an App Corner?

Tags: 8.1-update-1, apps-corner

In Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 there's a new feature called "app corner" where you can put apps like in the Kids Corner. I'm unable to find it on my Nokia Lumia 930 with Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1.

How do I access this new feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article explains how to do it:
http://www.wpcentral.com/how-to-set-up-apps-corner

> Here's how to set up Apps Corner:
>
> 1. Swipe down from the top of the screen and tap 'All settings.'
> 2. Scroll down and tap apps corner.
> 3. Tap 'Apps' and select the apps that you want people to use. Tap 'Done' when you're happy with your selection.
> 4. If your phone doesn't already have a lock screen password, you should set one now to make sure that people can't get to your Start screen from Apps Corner. Tap 'Protect my phone with a password,' type a password in the New password box, type it again in the Confirm password box, and then tap Done.
> 5. Turn Action Center and Settings on or off, depending on whether you want people to be able to use these features when using Apps Corner.
> 6. Tap Advanced, and then turn these features on or off, depending on whether you want people to be able to use them — Camera button, Search button, Start button, Back button, and Modify Tiles. Press the back button when you're glad with the settings.
> 7. Tap the launch button at the bottom to run Apps Corner.
> 8. Give the phone to someone else, so they can use it with only the apps and settings you've selected.